# What is the theme of “The Deserted Road” by Sheila Burnford?

Tags: theme, the-incredible-journey, sheila-burnford

What is the theme of “The Deserted Road” by Sheila Burnford? This is part of the novel, *The Incredible Journey*, but I want to figure out the theme for this short excerpt. It is shown that the animals have human-like intelligence, and as a result chose to leave their home, but I’m not sure if there is enough evidence to prove any theme.